# How to disable an item from a Kendo ToolBar at run time KendoUI?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

How I can put enable (TRUE OR FALSE) an item of KendoToolBar I tried to do this, but it does not work

```
var toolBar = $("#toolbar_1592").data("kendoToolBar");
toolBar.options.items[0].enable =false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the example below from https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/toolbar/methods/enable

```
 <div id="toolbar"></div>
    <script>
            $("#toolbar").kendoToolBar({
                items: [
                    { type: "button", id: "btn1", text: "Button 1", enable: true }
                ]
            });

        var toolbar = $("#toolbar").data("kendoToolBar");
        toolbar.enable("#btn1", false); //disables the initially disabled command
    </script>
```